# How can I catch response after third-party login-in with Google?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I want to implement Google login logic without Identity realization.
I am using .net 6 web API.

I base my logic on article [Adding Google Authentication In .Net Core Application Without Identity The Basics](https://blog.rashik.com.np/adding-google-authentication-in-net-core-application-without-identity/)

1. I provide the Credentials ( *Authorized redirect URIs*  in console.cloud.google):

`http://localhost:56895/Google/Challenge`

`http://localhost:56895/signin-google`

2. I configured program.cs (asp.net 6)

   ```
   services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Application";
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = "External";
        })
        .AddCookie("Application")
        .AddCookie("External")
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "<Id>";
            options.ClientSecret = "<Secret>";
        });
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {        
        [HttpGet("Google/Login")]
        [OpenApiOperation(
            operationId: "Google.Login",
            summary: "Google Login",
            description: "Google Login")
        ]
        [OpenApiTags("Google")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(
                GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:56895/Google/Challenge"
                });
        }


        [HttpGet("Google/Challenge")]
        [OpenApiOperation(
            operationId: "Google.Challenge",
            summary: "Google Challenge",
            description: "Google Challenge")
        ]
        [OpenApiTags("Google")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Challenge()
        {
            var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("External");
            if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
                return BadRequest();

            return Redirect("some URl");
        }
    }
   ```

[image]

But then a authorization the request go to wrong API endpoint. It has to go 'Google/Challenge' endpoint

[image]

I can't understand why it goes to signin-google and doesn't response to challenge endpoint?

Front-end side is Vue3 js. There is a link to login endpoint

```
<a href="http://localhost:56895/Google/Login">Sign up with Google</a>
```

I tried to send the request and catch callback but unfortunatelly I didn't recieve it

Comment: "Correlation failed" issues are typically caused by misconfigured cookies: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/483#issuecomment-706149314

Comment: Yor are right, after 'CookiePolicyOptions' configuration the response comes. Please make answer to approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Correlation failed" issues are often caused by misconfigured cookies for [SameSite](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/).

This can typically be resolved by updating the configuration in your `ConfigureServices()` (or similar) method.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.OnAppendCookie = ctx => SetSameSite(ctx.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = ctx => SetSameSite(ctx.CookieOptions);
});

static void SetSameSite(CookieOptions options)
{
    if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
    {
        options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    }
}
```

The above snippet was adapted from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/483#issuecomment-706149314).